# Monad transformer representing an infinite chain of actions?

Tags: haskell, while-loop, monads, monad-transformers

I attempted to implement a monad transformer representing an infinite chain of actions, like this:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Monad
import Data.Functor.Classes
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Semigroup
import Text.Read

import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Class as T

newtype WhileT m a = WhileT {uncons :: m (a, WhileT m a)}

instance T.MonadTrans WhileT where
    lift m = WhileT $ do
        x <- m
        pure (x, T.lift m)

headW :: Functor m => WhileT m a -> m a
headW (WhileT m) = fmap fst m

tailW :: Functor m => WhileT m a -> m (WhileT m a)
tailW (WhileT m) = fmap snd m

drop1 :: Monad m => WhileT m a -> WhileT m a
drop1 m = WhileT (tailW m >>= uncons)

dropN :: Monad m => Int -> WhileT m a -> WhileT m a
dropN n = appEndo (stimes n (Endo drop1))

instance Functor m => Functor (WhileT m) where
    fmap f (WhileT m) = WhileT (fmap (f *** fmap f) m)

instance Monad m => Applicative (WhileT m) where
    pure x = WhileT (pure (x, pure x))
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad m => Monad (WhileT m) where
    WhileT m >>= f = WhileT $ do
        (x, xs) <- m
        y <- headW (f x)
        let ys = xs >>= drop1 . f
        pure (y, ys)
```

The name `WhileT` is after C's `while`. It can be easily seen that `WhileT Identity` is a monad.

But what about other choices of `m`? In particular, judging by some experiments, `WhileT Maybe` seems to be equivalent to `ZipList`. But it is already known that there is no `instance Monad ZipList`. Does this mean `WhileT` isn't really a monad transformer?

## Edit

It seems this is the correct of way of implementing `instance Monad (WhileT m)`:

```
import Control.Applicative

instance MonadPlus m => Applicative (WhileT m) where
    pure x = WhileT (pure (x, empty))
    liftA2 = liftM2
    (<*>) = ap

instance MonadPlus m => Alternative (WhileT m) where
    empty = WhileT empty
    WhileT xs <|> WhileT ys = WhileT (xs <|> ys)

instance MonadPlus m => Monad (WhileT m) where
    WhileT xs >>= f = WhileT $ do
        (y, ys) <- xs
        uncons (f y) <|> uncons (ys >>= f)

instance MonadPlus m => MonadPlus (WhileT m)
```

Now `WhileT Identity` isn't even a monad, but hey, it was just `(->) Natural`.

Now `WhileT Maybe` is equivalent to `[]`. What about now? Any choice of `m` where `WhileT m` violates the monad laws?

Comment: This isn't a proof, but your type is isomorphic to [`MealyT m () a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines-0.7.2/docs/Data-Machine-MealyT.html#t:MealyT). Given that `MealyT` has Functor and Applicative instances but no Monad instance, that suggests that you can't have one that works generally over all monads `m`.

Comment: You might like to use the [`loop-while`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/loop-while-1.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-LoopWhile.html) package.

Answer (score 6):

The counterexample at [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/nfyvy/instance_monad_ziplist_where/) works for your `WhileT Maybe`, too.

```
-- to make these things a bit more convenient to type/read
fromListW :: [a] -> WhileT Maybe a
fromListW [] = WhileT Nothing
fromListW (x:xs) = WhileT (Just (x, fromListW xs))

xs = fromListW [1,2]

f 1 = fromListW [11]
f 2 = fromListW [21, 22]

g 11 = fromListW [111]
g 21 = fromListW []
g 22 = fromListW [221, 222]
```

Then, in ghci:

```
> (xs >>= f) >>= g
WhileT {uncons = Just (111,WhileT {uncons = Just (222,WhileT {uncons = Nothing})})}
> xs >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
WhileT {uncons = Just (111,WhileT {uncons = Nothing})}
```